# How to analize OVH server download speed and improve it

Tags: server, download, bandwidth

I have a dedicated 1gbps server with OVH, and CDN of Akamai.
When I download a 1.1 MB file using Akamai, I have a speed of total request of 319ms.
When I download a 1.1 MB file directly from my OVH server, I have speed of total request of: 1.43s.

When I analyze them in chrome:

Akamai request:

```
Request sent: 83 us
Waiting for server response: 183.86 ms
Content download: 134.58ms
```

OVH dedicated server:

```
Request sent: 68 us
Waiting for server response: 92.25 ms
Content download: 1.34s
```

The dedicated server comes with a 1gbps connection and I'm not using even hagh of this BW.
Looks like that `OVH` should be faster because my `Request sent` and `Waiting for server response` is faster, but the content download is much slower.

why is it? how can I change it? hat are the parameters that influence the download speed?

Comment: isn't it something you should check with OVH directly ? This is not a programing question

Comment: They aren't very responsive and I need to solve it fast :(